# C++ boolean logic syntax for xcode on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, boolean-logic

I just learned how to program in C++ this last week, and I wrote my first program using Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 express. My computer at home is a Mac and doesn't have MS Visual studios so I decided to use xcode and copy my code from MS visual studios into xcode. For the most part there aren't any errors except that xcode has a problem with my boolean logic syntax. Here are a few of the examples from my code that it has a problem with:

```
if(place == 1)
{

cout<< name << " 'IS NOW THE FASTEST JUNIOR IN THE UNITED STATES!!!\n";

cout<< "ABSOLUTLY INCREDIBLE!!!!! WHAT AN AMAZING RACE\n"
    << endl
    << endl;

cout<< "You did it! You won the race and are now the fastest Junior skier in the USA!\n";

cout<< "All that hard work really paid off for you!\n";

    <<endl;
}
else (place >1)
{
cout << "You skied a great race, but unfortunately you did not beat Ben.\n";

cout<< "You can always race again next year and shoot for gold.\n"
    <<endl;
}
```

The error that comes up says "Expression result unused." How do I fix this?

Comment: That doesn't look like proper C++. Else isn't given a condition like an if statement. Try `else if(place>1){ /* ... */ }`

Comment: Post the whole code or a significant snippet please.

Comment: @Hassan: I think it is valid code. You are right in pointing out that `else` does not work like `if`, `else (place > 1);` just means that in `else` section evaluate the value of `place > 1` and discard the result. @Chris Rouw: The error is meant to indicate that you are not using the values evaluated as part of the expressions `(place > 1)` & `(restStopDecision == 2)`

Comment: @another.anon.coward Ah I see. You're right, I don't think that is what the OP meant though. I think he might have meant `else if(...`, but there's no way to know without the rest of the code.

Comment: Do those two lines appear together in your program, or are they two separate snippets? It would help us (and future readers of this question) if you'd show a few more lines of context.

Comment: I added the portion of the code that was causing a problem. After I changed the else to else if, the program ran without a problem.

Comment: The code you've now included in your question contains a syntax error; the compiler would complain about that before, or instead of, the "Expression result unused" warning. If you add a semicolon after `else (place >1)`, then it becomes syntactically valid, but obviously not what you intended. (That's a problem with C and C++ grammar; it's easy to make one-character mistakes that aren't syntax errors, but that completely change the meaning of the code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with the first line of your code snippet (which was much easier to read and understand after formatting it properly):

```
else(place >1);
```

This is the last part of an `if` statement, and means that if the condition in the `if` was not true, then do the statement after `else`. In your case it's an expression that checks if `place` is larger than one then throw away the result, so it does nothing really. You probably mean to use `else if` instead of only `else`.

Then look at the next line:

```
else (restStopDecision == 2);
```

Here you do the same mistake again, but now with an `else` where none are supposed to be, which is an error in itself. You probably mean `else if` here too.

Comment: Possibly the second `else` is associated with a different `if` (whether or not it was intended to).

Comment: Thank you. I fixed those errors and the program now runs with out a problem.